# Clicking buttons (one at a time) and changing their icons

Tags: javascript

I have multiple images (that serves as a button) that if clicked, it will change the icon.

```
<img id = "i1" onClick = "changeImg()" src = "img1.png">
<img id = "i2" onClick = "changeImg()" src = "img2.png">
<img id = "i3" onClick = "changeImg()" src = "img3.png">
.....
```

Inside my function, this is what I tried to do:

```
for(var x = 1; x <=5; x++){
   if(document.getElementById("i"+x).src == "img" + x + ".png")
        document.getElementById("i"+x).src = "pic" + x + ".png")
}
```

But obviously, when I clicked a button (image), all the other buttons seem to be clicked also (and they all changed their icons). What I want to do is that if I clicked an image, that image, alone, will change its icon. Likewise if I clicked another image, and so on...

This may seem a simple one, (but I really can't think of a way to solve; i'm new at programming -- specifically javascript) please be nice.
Thanks for your help(in advanced).

Comment: You will need to use `this` within your `click` event. This way you can target just the element that was clicked. Also can you post the full `changeImg()` function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function changeImg(x) { 
    if(document.getElementById("i"+x).src == "img" + x + ".png")
        document.getElementById("i"+x).src = "pic" + x + ".png")
}
```

HTML:

```
<img id = "i1" onClick = "changeImg(1)" src = "img1.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `this` in every function to handle with its related content.

```
<img id = "i1" onClick = "changeImg(this)" src = "img1.png">
```

For example, with

```
function changeImg(tag) {
    alert(tag);
    // console.log(tag);
}
```

you can see what `this` means in this case.

To access the `src` of every tag:

```
function changeImg(tag) {
    alert(tag.src);
    // console.log(tag.src);
}
```

I would replace *img* with *pic* with the **replace** function:

```
str.replace(search, replacement);
```

[Example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Complete solution:

**HTML**

```
<img id = "i1" onClick = "changeImg(this)" src = "img1.png">
<img id = "i2" onClick = "changeImg(this)" src = "img2.png">
<img id = "i3" onClick = "changeImg(this)" src = "img3.png">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function changeImg(tag) {
    var id = tag.id;
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var src = tag.src;
    var newSrc = src.replace("img", "pic");
    el.src = newSrc;
}
```